# VSCode local git hooks

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, githooks

I have a project that sits in a monorepo. That monorepo is been shared among a lot of projects with different types. I have a React project with NPM in this monorepo.

We are using VSCode for the development of this repo, since there are verity of people (experts and less experts) that touch the code, I want to make the process as easy as possible to prevent issues for everyone. For example, run `npm install` if the `package.json` file has changed.

Since it is a monorepo, no one is allowed to create git hook for a specific sub project. So I search for a solution of "local git hooks" that will not impact other projects.

Since we are using VSCode and open the root **project** directory in it, is there any way to create "local" git hooks in VSCode? For example, if someone run `git pull` in the VSCode the VSCode will execute additional command after like a hook?

Comment: Any .git hooks that run locally need to be set up by each user, as they are not included when cloning or fetching from the repo. See [8.3 Customizing Git - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But since this is a monorepo (even if it private hook for the user) will trigger for every project. For example, if I use the `post-merge` hook for auto `npm install` it will trigger if I work on another project in the same repo. I want something similar but for the current workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been in a similar situation and ended up using [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) in conjunction with [Yarn Workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/)

It's been working great for us - the only thing that every developer needs to know is to run `yarn` after cloning, and all tools will be installed.

The only caveat in your situation is that you will need to write your own hook for e.g. running `npm install` if the pulled commits contain `package.json` changes, but that shouldn't be very hard to do - `husky` hooks are plain `bash` scripts after all.